# Upload multiple TXT Files and validate length of columns on each

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, validation, file-upload

I have a bat to import .txt files to database,its a pain,so have started to build a web import, i have done with only one input but need to import multiple

Its the path of the process

Upload the files
Validate lenght of columns of the file ex: "if housenumber <>6 then..."
if all of the columns have the correct lengths pass to the second file

Its working with only the first file of input

function impjucespupload(Request $request)
    {
    $qtdarquivos = count($request->file('upload-file')); //get total of files uploaded

```
$upload = $request->file('upload-file');
foreach($upload as $file){
    $name = $file->getRealPath();
    $data[]=$name; //make array with the multiple files
}

$i=0;

for($a=1;$a< $qtdarquivos; $a++){ //validate the first file of the array upload
    $file = fopen($data[$a],'r');

    while (($line = fgets($file)) !== false){
        $data = explode(chr(9) , $line);
        $locks[$a][$i] = array(
            0 => $data[0],
            1 => $data[1],
            2 => $data[2],
            3 => $data[3],
            4 => str_replace("\n", "", $data[4])
        );
        $i++;
        }


        $tamanho = count($locks); //get total of lines 

        $d = 0;
        $e = 0;
        $erro = 0;
        for ($e = 0; $e < $tamanho; $e++) //iterate the columns of txt
            {
            if (strlen($locks[$a][$d][0]) <> 6)
                {
                $erro = 1;

                return back()->withErrors('Rolo Inválido na Linha ' . $d = $d + 1); // stop and return alert to view if found any error
                }
              else // 
                {
                $d++; //iterate the next line of the first file 
                }
            }
          $a++; //sum +1 to go for the validation of next file uploaded that be in on $data[]array

          $b++; //For open the second file
}
```

I just need to upload an exemple of 10 .txts and validate the length of columns , and just break if found any error then insert on database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're overwriting your `$data` variable within your `while` loop.

```
while (($line = fgets($file)) !== false){
    $data = explode(chr(9) , $line);
```

Change the second line to use a different variable name.

Comment: But its not supossed to be overwrited here? 


 $file = fopen($data[$b],'r');     // $b = array of files uploaded

Comment: Thanks, i have back to this project and have seen muito fault